# GetGestureInfo returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER only in release mode

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, touch, gestures

I have following WM_GESTURE processing code:

```
    case WM_GESTURE:
    {
        GESTUREINFO gi;

        ZeroMemory(&gi, sizeof(gi));

        gi.cbSize = sizeof(gi);

        BOOL bResult = GetGestureInfo((HGESTUREINFO)lParam, &gi);
        BOOL bHandled = FALSE;

        if (bResult){
            // Gesture processing code is here, but it never gets here in release mode
        }
        else{
            DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
            // Here it returns 87 in release mode
        }

        CloseGestureInfoHandle((HGESTUREINFO)lParam);
```

The gesture processing works 100% fine in debug mode, but it breaks in release mode - the GetGestureInfo returns false and the followup GetLastError call returns 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says it might be because gi.cbSize is not set correctly, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Why?

Comment: Did you verify that `sizeof(gi)` is actually the same value in both modes?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It is 48 in debug mode and 40 in release mode. Is that an issue?

Comment: Yes. The size of the structure needs to be consistent. The physical members of the struct add up to 40 bytes, so the extra 8 bytes have to be padding in between some of the members. That indicates the structure is likely being QWORD (64bit) aligned in debug mode but DWORD (32bit) aligned in release mode. The function has no concept of the alignment your code is using, it only cares that the structure is large enough so it can access the members correctly. Sounds like the function itself expects QWORD alignment.

Comment: The definition of `GESTUREINFO` is likely missing a required `#pragma` to force the correct alignment in all compiling modes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So what is the most correct fix to this? Right now the code indeed works with hard-coded 48, but I don't exactly like it as a solution. And I don't even want to try 64bit build.

Comment: If the true size is 40 but you set `cbSize` to 48, that is likely to cause stack corruption. Which compiler are using? Are you using the standard Win32 header files, or did you declare `GESTUREINFO` manually? I find it unlikely that the standard declaration in `winuser.h` would have this mismatch, Microsoft is pretty good about avoiding that. I will have to check the standard declaration when I have time to make sure it is aligned properly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau VS 2013, Windows Platform SDK for WIn 8.1. I use standard header files (windows.h).

Comment: You may want to check your "struct member alignment settings" (Project Settings-> C++ -> Code Generation). Its usually set to Default. But I had a case, where it was set to another value causing the problem. In release and debug configuration by the way.